# Is the placeholder text in a content editable div counted as disabled text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, high-contrast

With IE and using Window's default Black high contrast mode, the disabled text should have a green color. However, I found in my app, the placeholder text in `<input>` does have a green color but the placeholder text in content-editable div will remain the color I give it in normal mode.
Below is the HTML I wrote:

```
 <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Name" aria-label="Enter your name" tabindex="1"></input>
 <div  contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="in case this div is empty"></div>
 The css for the div to work is div {margin:1em; border:solid;}
                                div:empty:before {content:attr(data-placeholder);
                                                  color:gray}
```

The div example can be found at http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/hzLIE.
What is really the concept of disabled text? I'm guessing placeholder in content-editable div will not be counted as 'disabled text'? If so, how to make it a 'disabled text'?
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: you are using pseudo element, wich are unseen from javascript and are not disabled text but generated content. this pen you linked is getting old :)

Comment: @GCyrillus Could you please explain more why the pseudo element is generating content? Why the placeholder attribute in <input> doesn't generate content?

Comment: @GCyrillus Could you give some hint about how to make a content editable div placeholder text a disabled text? In other word, how to add placeholder text to content editable div without using pseudo element (Without generating content)?

Comment: what you could is eventually give a color to the pseudo and take a look at : http://www.sitepoint.com/css-system-styles/ to define your colors. input, image, textarea are some of the elements where pseudos element are not avalaible, but input and textarea takes the `placeholder=" type this";` attribute

Comment: listing of os system colors on msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @GCyrillus Thanks for the comments :) I thought about adding a color to the pseudo element before. But I think the problem is disabled text color in high contrast mode can be adjusted by users. If we give it a fixed color, it may not work when users change the default disabled color